# Django AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Successful but site not responsive

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my own API. I am using Django and the Django Rest Framework. I have uploaded my Django via Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface via `eb init` and `eb create`.

I am following this tutorial and have followed all of the steps:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

I have successfully created my environment and uploaded my app:

[image: Command Line Info]
[image: AWS Console Info]

However, when I hit up the url via `eb open`, this shows:

[image]

How do I debug something that tells me nothing is broken? I feel like something is off. My intuition tells me it has to do with me trying to serve my API over SSL. I currently have my Django app redirect all http requests to https. Do I have to run `manage.py runsslserver`? Do I need to install any environment things from my `requirements.txt` file?

EDIT: Normally when I run `python manage.py runsslserver`, I'm greeted with this on localhost. I have set up an api-root and expected to see that when I hit the EBS url.
[image]

Comment: That is the URL of the server. I believe you are missing the app name in the URL

Comment: What do you mean? My app was called API for Elastic Beanstalk. Do I append that or something?

Comment: Do you have any views in django or is it just your DRF app? if you do not have any views what are your routes? How do you call your app locally after the localhost:8000? that's what you should append

Comment: Yes I do, but I also have a root one that is simply the url of the app. I have updated my question with a picture.

Comment: Try just for testing to serve it both on HTTP and HTTPS on the EBS console. And see if you can access the HTTP version. That will at least let you know if it's SSL the problem

Comment: Wait no, I fixed that a while ago. The timestamp is in UTZ. I'm not sure what is wrong. Regular HTTP doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114493/discussion-between-sticky-and-aquiles).

Comment: hi i am facing the same issue were you able to fix it?

Comment: @Sticky did you end up solving this? What was the solution?

Comment: I did not :( sorry